# How to Make a Shell Script Run on a Sleep Timer?

Tags: bash

My code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
COLLECTIONS_DIRECTORY="./test/collections"
DATA_DIRECTORY="./test/data"

WEBSITE_LOADED=false

while [ "$WEBSITE_LOADED" = false ]; do
    echo Checking to see if WEBSITE is loaded
    RESPONSE_CODE=$(curl -o /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}' "http://127.0.0.1/testpage.aspx")
    echo $RESPONSE_CODE
    if [ "$RESPONSE_CODE" = 200 ]; then
        echo WEBSITE loaded
        WEBSITE_LOADED=true
    fi
    sleep 5s
done
```

The issue is that I have a response like this:

[image: Checking to see if WEBSITE is loaded]

The problem here is that this happens for every second. So it is like the `sleep 5s` is not working like it should in the code above.

Am I doing the correct thing here?
Is the `sleep 5s` in the correct area of the code?

Comment: Why you tagged this with `javascript` is beyond me.

Comment: What you're seeing is the output of the `curl` command, which by default prints progress updates every second. Your `sleep 5` command isn't running at all, and won't run until `curl` exits, allowing the script to continue.

Comment: Use `curl -sS` to silence curl.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, so it would look like this? `curl -sS -o /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}' "http://127.0.0.1/testpage.aspx"`

Comment: Sorry @FedericoklezCulloca, my knowledge of Javascript isn't that good. I should've looked closely to the comment at the top of the file :)

Comment: @Kevdog777 yes .

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @KamilCuk, that has worked now.